# Does Google Apps Script V8 engine support Promise?

Tags: google-apps-script, v8

They say the V8 engine is a proper Javascript ES5 engine. Does it support ES5 features like Promise?

Comment: Syntactically Yes.  Functionally No.

Answer (score 5):

No. Promises are not functionally supported. But all promises related syntax is valid and doesn't throw any error. However everything runs synchronously.

```
async function promise1_() {
  Logger.log("Start")
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  return "done";
}

function test1(){
  promise1_();
  Logger.log("End")
}
```

If promises worked, "End" should be logged before "Start", but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Apps script V8 recognizes the new function definition formats, for example:

> `let letAsyncFunction = async function() { //Your logic here }`

It asynchronously returns the result of the function evaluations, pretty much like a Promise.

In other words, when the function `async` is called, it returns a promise. Also `await` is used for calling an async function and wait for it to resolve or reject

---

**References:**

- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [V8 runtime Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#improved_function_detection)

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit old yet still relevant.

My answer is **No** (Apr. 2022).
Although syntactically and the way the code runs yes, but practically it is synchronous flow.

#### example:

```
function main() {
    console.log(Date(),"start");

    getStatAsync();
    
    console.log(Date(),"end");

}

 function getStatAsync(){

    let p = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
let url = "some url";
    
        let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

        let ans = parse(response);

        if (ans){
            res(ans);
        }else{
            rej("fetch faild");
        }
    })

  //resolved
    p.then((res) =>{
        console.log("fetch resolved",res);
    })

  //rejected
    p.catch((msg) => {
        console.log("fetch failure", msg );
    })

    function parse(response){
        let ans = null;

        let code = response.getResponseCode();

        if (code == "200" ) {
            ans = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
          } else {
            console.error(` fetch failed code=${code}`);
          }

          return ans;
    }
}

main()
```

this is semi code fetching for a URL from within a Promise.

The promise is wrapping `UrlFetchApp` is within a promise that logs the fetch results either is the then or the catch callbacks.

The output for that would be:

1. **start**
2. **end**
3. for successful fetch: **fetch resolved**

The **end** message is logged before the promise logging, indicating asynchronous execution.
Without the promise **end** message become the last log line and the **fetch resolved** becomes last as in standard synchronous flow

However, assuming the fetch takes 10 sec, both **end** and **fetch resolved** are logged after those 10 sec.

The main code is suspended until fetch returned, although the log lines seems are printed like it is asynchronous flow